# How to Increment duplicate strings in a column

Tags: postgresql-9.2

I have a table similar to what is below.  I have listed only one column since that's what I'm interested in.

```
| column 
---------
| foo
| foo
| foo
| bar
| bar
| bar
```

Below is the output that I desire but I can't seem to figure out how to make it happen.  This column is not a primary key or serial key.

```
| column 
---------
| foo 1
| foo 2
| foo 3
| bar 1
| bar 2
| bar 3
```

I want to increment the string if there are duplicates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the row number window function for this (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-window.html)

```
SELECT col || ' ' || row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY col) 
FROM test_a;
```

Output will be:

```
+------------+
| ?column?   |
|------------|
| bar 1      |
| bar 2      |
| bar 3      |
| bar 4      |
| foo 1      |
| foo 2      |
| foo 3      |
| foo 4      |
+------------+
```